# WndProc does not work when window is out of focus

Tags: c#, sendmessage, wndproc

I wanted to use `SendMessage` to a `WM_COPYDATA` from a global hook `dll`, and then send it to my`Mainwindow` `WndProc`. `WndProc` only listens to procs when it is the active screen, and does not receive the message being sent by the `dll` when it is out of focus.

Is this a limitation of WndProc? are there better alternatives to this?

Comment: Is `WM_COPYMESSAGE` a new kind of message from Windows 11?

Comment: my bad, I meant to say WM_COPYDATA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem to be the `HWND` being used on my `SendMessage` call. It has to be shared by all dlls like so:

```
#pragma data_seg("Shared")
//our hook handle which will be returned by calling SetWindowsHookEx function
HHOOK hkKey = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInstHookDll = NULL;  //our global variable to store the instance of our DLL
HWND pHWnd = NULL; // global variable to store the mainwindow handle
#pragma data_seg() //end of our data segment

#pragma comment(linker,"/section:Shared,rws")
// Tell the compiler that Shared section can be read,write and shared

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK procCharMsg(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
//this is the hook procedure
{
    //a pointer to hold the MSG structure that is passed as lParam
    MSG* msg;
    //to hold the character passed in the MSG structure's wParam
    char charCode;
    if (nCode >= 0 && nCode == HC_ACTION)
        //if nCode is less than 0 or nCode
        //is not HC_ACTION we will call CallNextHookEx
    {
        //lParam contains pointer to MSG structure.
        msg = (MSG*)lParam;
        if (msg->message == WM_CHAR)
            //we handle only WM_CHAR messages
        {
            SendMessage(pHWnd, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)msg->message, (LPARAM)0); // This should now work globally
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hkKey, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

// called by main app to establish a pointer of itself to the dlls
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int SetParentHandle(HWND hWnd) {
    pHWnd = hWnd;
    if (pHWnd == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I should have posted my code along with the problem, since little things are always pretty hard to spot alone.